# form fields not appearing inside the object hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a Rails form to create an "event" (that's nested inside a group resource) with the following fields. The fields `when` and `exactwhen` (extremely poorly named, i know, I'm just creating a quick demo) are meant to refer to date and time

```
<%= form_for [@group, @event], url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag(:title, "Event Title") %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= label_tag(:description, "Event Description") %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, size: "60x12" %>
  <%= label_tag(:address, "Address") %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= label_tag(:when, "When") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:when) %>
   <%= label_tag(:exactwhen, "exactwhen") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:exactwhen) %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

These fields exist on the event model in the database

```
 create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "address"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.date     "when"
    t.time     "exactwhen"
  end
```

However, when I submit the form, you'll notice that `when` and `exactwhen` are not contained in the event hash

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5kkL2a3yDHEINSqSg+1cXd708GtRPgymbKmASs+eih8=", "event"=>{"title"=>"First Wankers Meeting", "description"=>"get drunk", "address"=>"57 Robert Crescent"}, "when"=>"08/23/2013", "exactwhen"=>"12", "commit"=>"Create", "group_id"=>"38"}
```

and the data for `when` and `exactwhen` are not getting inserted into the record

```
 Group Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "38"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("address", "created_at", "description", "group_id", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["address", "57 Robert Crescent"], ["created_at", Sat, 03 Aug 2013 16:38:30 UTC +00:00], ["description", "get drunk"], ["group_id", 38], ["title", "First Wankers Meetup"], ["updated_at", Sat, 03 Aug 2013 16:38:30 UTC +00:00]]
```

I'm assuming that the form data for `when` and `exactwhen` are not getting inserted into the db because they're not in the event hash. If that's the case, can you explain why, or explain how I could otherwise correct this problem?

This is the create action in the events_controller.rb

```
 def create
      @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
      @event = @group.events.build(event_params)
      if @event.save
      ....


    private
    def event_params

      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :when, :exactwhen, :address)

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using form_for. Change all your fields (and labels) to normal fields, not tag fields. So change text_field_tag to text_field.

If you do that, everything should work. Then all the attributes should be in the right params hash.

For more info check out form_for in the rails api docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `f.text_field` instead of `text_field_tag` like you do with the first few form fields